# Cloth simulation not working properly

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

Below is the cloth simulation image from blender and the settings I used for simulation. But I am not getting why the cloth is inflating after baking process and it shrinks from its original size.I tried every material but behavior is same.
Can anyone help me with this?
[image]

Comment: My first guess would be that one or both of your "Distance" settings is too high. Try setting them both to '0.001' and see what happens.

Comment: It didn't work with 0.001 but it worked with 0.07. It was falling down if I was entering 0.001. Earlier it was 0.2. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `Distance` setting is too high/large. There are two places where `Distance` is specified, and they are different settings.

One of them is the distance from the mesh that `collision` objects will be considered "colliding." If you set this too high, the mesh will behave as though it's colliding, even though it's not touching. If you set this too low, the mesh might move too far over the course of a frame, and the collision will never be detected.

The other place that `Distance` is specified is specifically for the cloth interacting with itself. Another part of the cloth that is within the specified distance will be considered "self-colliding." Similar principles apply.

Answer (score 1):

I had to lower the Thickness Outer value under Softbody and Cloth on the collision object. That allowed the cloth settle on the body.